# M4P to MP3 converter

Tags: itunes, conversion, mp3

Does anybody have experience converting M4P protected audio files (itunes protected files) to MP3 without ripping to a bunch of cds? If so, which program did you use? Ive tried one called tune clone but its not freeware and I dont have that many songs. Any recommendations, or is there no good freeware for such a task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a paid app called TuneClone. There is no freeware currently on the market to do this. There used to be but it got shut off or terminated operation for whatever reason.

TuneClone did not work well but it got the job done for me. I had to create a playlist for every "cd burn" and burn them one cd at a time, which was almost equivalent to burning physical cds, but it saved me the time of ripping the cd's (and of course you don't actually use real cds when you use this program). I dont recommend it unless your desperate or have a small amount of songs to convert (which I did). Don't bother with the trial version, it cuts songs off at 3 minutes.